# How can i send email in Android

Tags: android, email

I want send email in my application, i write below code and i want give subject and email content from `EditText` and send this text into email client! but when use this and go to email client not sending text!

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_send_idea);
                    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

                    EditText dialogTitle = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ideaDialog_title);
                    EditText dialogDescription = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ideaDialog_description);
                    Button dialogSend = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ideaDialog_sendButton);
                    final String emailTitle = dialogTitle.getText().toString();
                    final String emailDescription = dialogDescription.getText().toString();

                    dialogSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent sendEmailItent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            sendEmailItent.setType("message/rfc822");
                            sendEmailItent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"tellfa.group@gmail.com"});
                            sendEmailItent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailTitle);
                            sendEmailItent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , emailDescription);
                            try {
                                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendEmailItent, "ارسال با : "));
                            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                                TastyToast.makeText(context, "برنامه مورد نظر یافت نشد", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.WARNING);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    dialog.show();
```

How can i give text from user in EditText and pass this into email client? Thanks all

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
final String emailTitle = dialogTitle.getText().toString();
final String emailDescription = dialogDescription.getText().toString();
```

These statements are being executed when the dialog is created. The user has not typed anything in yet.

You need to retrieve the typed-in text inside of your `onClick()` method, as that is executed when the user clicks your "send" button.

Comment: how can solve my problem my friend? can you help me and send some code? please

Answer (score 0):

This is what @Commonsware's answer would look like implemented. Plus some error checking.

```
     dialogSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if(dialogTitle.getText().toString().isEmpty(){
                            dialogTitle.setError("Subject must not be empty");
                        }else if(emailDescription.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                            emailDescription.setError("Content must not be empty");
                        }else{

                            Intent sendEmailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            sendEmailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                            sendEmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"tellfa.group@gmail.com"});
                            sendEmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailTitle);
                            sendEmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , emailDescription);
                            try {
                                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendEmailIntent, "ارسال با : "));
                            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                                TastyToast.makeText(context, "برنامه مورد نظر یافت نشد", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.WARNING);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```